# Does the code inside a Future have chances to run before the code in main thread after that?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

If I run the following code,

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

println("### start")

Future {
  println("### enter future")
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  println("### exit future")
}

println("### end")
```

It prints:

```
### start
### end
### enter future
```

You can see the `### end` is before `### enter future`.

My question is, is there any chance that `### enter future` will be printed before `### end`?

I guess it could be, because when I run `Future {}`, it will put the task in a thread pool. Since the thread switch point is uncertained, it may have a chance to switch from the main thread to the thread inside the pool. In this case, `### enter future` will be printed before `### end`

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a small chance the future will execute first. Try putting `Thread.sleep(1000)` before `println("### end")`.

Comment: Furthermore, if you were to execute two of those futures in sequence like that, there wouldn't even be a guarantee that either one would execute first, let alone what's happening in the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Since the `Future` is executing in another thread and you're not doing any synchronisation between them whoever gets to print first is an open race and since the main thread is already running there's a very high chance that it will print first.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there are no execution order guarantees between creator of a `Future` and the body of the `Future`. In your example, on a single threaded machine it is unlikely that the creating thread is suspended while creating the future, but even that isn't guaranteed and on any multi-core machine any assumptions about execution order go out the window.

I know with Twitter's `Future`, there's some attempt to see if the code can be executed inline, i.e. if it contains no blocking calls. I do not think the scala native `Future` does this, but simplly schedules the future on the `ExecutionContext`'s ThreadPool.